# How to set parameters to a storyboard in wpf?

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

Let's say that I have this storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnterStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="180" />
            </Storyboard>
```

It's there a possibility that I can set the `To` property from code. Something like

```
DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="{Binding angle}" />
```

And when I want to apply this animation to have a possibility to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree with what @Paul said : Storyboard property bindings are no different from "normal" way of binding properties.

Anyway, [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/befa8423-ee3f-4d62-bf50-fe409b179016/), [this](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-bind-to-animation-to-and-from.html), [this](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=7e03c916-5232-4e48-b79e-6e6d0bd698c9), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511345/bind-to-animated-property-wpf/511557#511557), and [this](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=7e03c916-5232-4e48-b79e-6e6d0bd698c9) are the links that you should follow if you want some good examples on Storyboard and Animation with property binding.

---

Answer (score 0):

Storyboards can have bindings, just like anything else - instead of trying to dig through and set this explicitly, bind it to something easier to get ahold of like the Window object or a ViewModel

Comment: Could you give me an example. I really don't understand your idea. I'm a beginner in WFP