# Why bindings don't work with animations?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, binding

I have a simple problem with an animated binded property. Here is a simple example to illustrate it :

**ViewModel :**

```
public class ViewModel
{

    private double myProperty;

    public double MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set { myProperty = value; /* Break point here */ }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyProperty = 20;
    }

}
```

**MyControl :**

```
public class MyControl : Button
{

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        base.OnClick();
        Height = ActualHeight + 20;
    }

}
```

**MyAnimatedControl :**

```
public class MyAnimatedControl : Button
{

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        base.OnClick();
        DoubleAnimation a = new DoubleAnimation(ActualHeight + 20, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
        this.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, a);
    }

}
```

**MainWindow :**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyAnimatedControl Height="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Animated"/>
        <local:MyControl Height="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Normal 1"/>
        <local:MyControl Height="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Normal 2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have two controls inherited from [Button](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx&ei=h7KeU7_pG-i7ygO8hAE&usg=AFQjCNHk7kpQbqQgdWMfH3npql_ncWHaFw&bvm=bv.68911936,d.bGQ&cad=rja) (MyControl and MyAnimatedControl), their Height property is binded (mode two way) to the MyProperty property in the ViewModel.

When the controls are clicked, they grow their Height property. The MyControl assigns it a new value and the MyAnimatedControl animates it.

**Problem :**

When I click one of the MyControl, the bindings work correctly, all the controls' heights are updated, the break point works in the ViewModel. But when I click the MyAnimatedControl, the binding seems to not work anymore : it grows alone and the binding doesn't work anymore whereas the two normal controls still grow together. It doesn't share the same height with to other controls anymore.

Is there a way to have an operational binding on an animated dependency property, which will update the ViewModel all along the animation? I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511345/bind-to-animated-property-wpf) but it doesn't answer it.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly happens when you click the animatedcontrol? Does it work one time? What is the value of actualheight?

Comment: If you click only on the normal controls, all the 3 controls in the MainWindow are updated and they all grow. When you click on the animated control, it grows alone and the binding doesn't work anymore whereas the two normal controls still grow together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the animated property is at the same time the source of the binding. To get around this, you could create another height property (e.g. `MyHeight`) that gets updated whenever the control's height changes and that serves as the target of a `OneWayToSource` binding.

```
public class MyAnimatedControl : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyHeight", typeof(double), typeof(MyAnimatedControl));

    public double MyHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MyHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        MyHeight = sizeInfo.NewSize.Height;
    }
}
```

The binding:

```
<local:MyAnimatedControl ...
   MyHeight="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
   Height="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

---

In order to get the other binding targets updated, you would also need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double myProperty = 30;
    public double MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set
        {
            myProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally, as Rohit Vats has written in his answer, you'll need to remove the hold of the animation on the Height property inside the Completed event handler:

```
protected override void OnClick()
{
    base.OnClick();
    DoubleAnimation a = new DoubleAnimation(ActualHeight + 20,
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
    a.Completed += (s, e) =>
    {
        BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, null); // Remove animation.
        SetCurrentValue(Button.HeightProperty, ActualHeight); // Set value.
    };
    this.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, a);
}
```

Comment: +1 Your solution is great but doesn't work with the two way mode. Good lead anyway.

Comment: It works perfectly also with TwoWay, at least for me. How did you try it?

Comment: If you simply replace the OneWayToSource by the TwoWay mode, it doesn't change the behavior of your code (i.e if the MyProperty of the ViewModel is updated, it won't change the Height property of the MyAnimatedControl)

Comment: You would still one-way bind the `Height` property to your view model (see my edit). However, he initial value if the VM property is ignored due to execution order of the bindings. But I have to admit that having an additional height property seems to be too complicated.

Comment: If you provide a bit more information about *why* you want to do this in the first place, we might perhaps provide a completely different solutuon. Is it really only about resizing some buttons, either animated or not?

Comment: You're right. I simply use an existing library to manipulate very large images. The main control contains a Scale dependeny property, which can be both assigned (equal operator) or animated. I want my ViewModel to be able to update AND to know in real time the value of this scale. I thought that the binding would have been the best way to do it but I got stuck with the animation part. With both your answer and Rohit's, I'm really not far of it, I'm still working on it. Thanks for you time anyway.

Comment: Ok, indeed your solution works fine for me IF I add the Completed event handler of Clemens when I create the animation. Would you edit your solution to add it? Then i'll accept it. Thank you very much to you three!

Answer (score 3):

Issue is animation has higher precedence order so when it gets applied to any property subsequent changes in that property won't reflect back on UI and in binding.

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can solve this with three approaches:

1. Set the animation's FillBehavior to Stop.
2. Remove the entire storyBoard.
3. Remove the animation from individual property.

In your case we can use third option to **remove animation from Height DP** after animation is completed.

---

Second, you should call [**SetCurrentValue**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) method to set the DP which will update the binding and hence update the bound ViewModel property.

---

Put all this in **`Completed`** event of **`DoubleAnimation`**:

```
public class MyAnimatedControl : Button
{

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        base.OnClick();
        DoubleAnimation a = new DoubleAnimation(ActualHeight + 20,
                                  new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
        a.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, null); // Remove animation.
            SetCurrentValue(Button.HeightProperty, ActualHeight); // Set value.
        };
        this.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, a);
    }
}
```

Also make sure your ViewModel is implementing [**INotifyPropertyChanged**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and property changed event is raised from **`MyProperty`** setter.

Comment: +1 Thank you for those explanations and this solution, but I looking for a way to update the value in the ViewModel in real time all along the animation, not just at the end. I don't know if there is a clean walk around to do this...

Comment: In that case creating another DP is the only solution which Clemens has already mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `Control.Height` property is a `DependencyProperty` and `DependencyProperty`s can be set from a variety of sources, eg. `Style Setter`, `Animation`, from code, etc. Because of this reason, Microsoft had to define an order of precedence to decide which of these possible ways to change the `DependencyProperty` value were more important than others.

It was logically decided that setting a `DependencyProperty` from an `Animation` as you do in your example should 'override' values set from other sources, eg. from a property setter. For full information of the `DependencyProperty` value precedence list, please see the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

However, using *your* code, I could not reproduce your problem. I could repeatedly click on each and every `Button` and see it continually growing in size. Therefore, if you couldn't do that, then I suspect that you have some other code somewhere interfering with this. If that was *not* your problem, then please clearly explain what is.

---

UPDATE >>>

Oh I think I see what you're after now... you're wondering why your property setter is not called when the `Animation` animates the property value. However, that won't work because `Animation`s don't permanently change property values. From the Data Binding and Animating Animations section of the [Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx#databindingAndAnimatingAnimationsSection) page:

> Most animation properties can be data bound or animated; for example, you can animate the `Duration` property of a `DoubleAnimation`. However, because of the way the timing system works, data bound or animated animations do not behave like other data bound or animated objects.

Comment: Thanks for those usefull information. Yeah, I must have not been totally clear. They indeed grow every time you click but the animated control will not share the same height (contained in the ViewModel) as the two normal controls.

Comment: @Max. Are you talking about this:  a.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;

Comment: @Core-One I know thos property but it didn't help me for this problem.

Comment: @Sheridan +1 Yes, thank you for your edit, I think my problem comes from this.