# WPF Modifying OneWayToSource bound property in ControlTemplate's storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, storyboard, controltemplate

I need to know whether my custom control used for displaying messages is currently displaying something. I have added a property to hold this information to my control and to my Viewmodel and I'm trying to update this property inside a storyboard from the control's ControlTemplate. However it seems that the property is not being updated (it's always false).

My control's property:

```
public class InfoBanner : Control
{
    (...)

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage", typeof(bool), typeof(InfoBanner), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessageProperty, value); }
    }

  (...)

}
```

The property in my InfoBannerViewModel (which is a field of the main viewmodel):

```
private bool isCurrentlyDisplayingMessage = false;

    public bool IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage
    {
        get { return isCurrentlyDisplayingMessage; }
        set
        {
            if (isCurrentlyDisplayingMessage != value)
            {
                isCurrentlyDisplayingMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage");
            }
        }
    }
```

The control put in xaml

```
<local:InfoBanner x:Name="MainInfoBanner" IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage="{Binding InfoBannerViewModel.IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  Message="{Binding InfoBannerViewModel.CurrentMessage, Mode=OneWay}" MessageType="{Binding InfoBannerViewModel.CurrentMessageType, Mode=OneWay}"  Style="{StaticResource InfoBannerStyle1}" />
```

The control template's storyboard

```
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardShowMessage">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="1"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="False" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

I have also tried creating the storyboard in the style, instead of the control template, but it did not work either. The bindings for the message that go the other way seem to work correctly. It is only the OneWayToSource binding that does not seem to work, I do not understand why.

EDIT: I have created a clean WPF project with just the relevant parts, without multiple viewmodels etc., to make it easier to find the bug. 
I have added functionality in MainWindow.xaml.cs to play the storyboard (via invoking a routedEvent) with a keypress, and then I can print to console current values of IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage in the control and in ViewModel. If I do that when the storyboard is playing I can clearly see, that the property value inside the control is set to True (the storyboard works correctly), but the value in ViewModel remains unchanged (False), meaning it is not propagated by the OneWayToSourceBinding.
[image: Console output image of the values explained above]

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="OneWayToSourceProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OneWayToSourceProject"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MyViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="InfoBannerTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type local:InfoBanner}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardShowMessage">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="1"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="False" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="500" Height="150" Opacity="0.0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="InfoBannerTextBlock" FontSize="24" Text="{TemplateBinding Message}" Foreground="#FF000000" Height="71.46" Canvas.Left="140.12" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="10" Width="259.031"/>
            </Canvas>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:InfoBanner.ShowInfoBanner">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ShowInfoBanner_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardShowMessage}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="InfoBannerStyle1">
            <Setter Property="local:InfoBanner.Template" Value="{StaticResource InfoBannerTemplate1}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <local:InfoBanner x:Name="MainInfoBanner"  Message="{Binding CurrentMessage, Mode=OneWay}" IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage="{Binding IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource InfoBannerStyle1}" Height="200" Canvas.Left="-12.259" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Top="0" Width="500" />

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace OneWayToSourceProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyViewModel();
            KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindowKeyDown);
        }

        private string[] messages = new string[] { "msg1", "msg2", "msg3" };
        private int msgIndx = 0;
        private void MainWindowKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.C)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Property value: " + MainInfoBanner.IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage.ToString() + " viewmodel value: " + ((MyViewModel)DataContext).IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage.ToString());
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.M)
            {
                ((MyViewModel)DataContext).CurrentMessage = messages[msgIndx];
                msgIndx = (msgIndx + 1) % messages.Length;
                MainInfoBanner.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(InfoBanner.ShowInfoBannerEvent));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace OneWayToSourceProject
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }


        private string message = "startingMessage";

        public string CurrentMessage
        {
            get { return message; }
            set
            {
                if (message != value)
                {
                    message = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMessage");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool isCurrentlyDisplayingMessage_ = false;

        public bool IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage
        {
            get { return isCurrentlyDisplayingMessage_; }
            set
            {
                if (isCurrentlyDisplayingMessage_ != value)
                {
                    isCurrentlyDisplayingMessage_ = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

InfoBanner.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace OneWayToSourceProject
{
    public class InfoBanner : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Message", typeof(string), typeof(InfoBanner), new PropertyMetadata());

        public string Message
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage", typeof(bool), typeof(InfoBanner), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessageProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly RoutedEvent ShowInfoBannerEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ShowInfoBanner", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(InfoBanner));

        public event RoutedEventHandler ShowInfoBanner
        {
            add
            {
                this.AddHandler(ShowInfoBannerEvent, value);
            }

            remove
            {
                this.RemoveHandler(ShowInfoBannerEvent, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your storyboard is making the property go from True to False when you want the opposite.

Comment: I want the value to be true for the 2 seconds when the storyboard is playing, and then I want to flip it back to false, which is why the storyboard is the way it is. Just for debugging I have changed it to only set the value to True, but it still remains False in the viewmodel. This makes me think there must be something wrong with the way I am using OneWayToSource binding.

Comment: I just tested it and it works as expected. You must have a Binding error in your output. I would guess that InfoBannerViewModel is the Datacontext of your xaml so the Binding should be IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage="{Binding InfoBannerViewModel.IsCurrentlyDisplayingMessage, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  Message="{Binding CurrentMessage, Mode=OneWay}" MessageType="{Binding InfoBannerViewModel.CurrentMessageType, Mode=OneWay}". If so your Bindings for Message and MessageType are also wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have made this clear in OP. InfoBannerViewModel isn't the data context, it's a field of the main ViewModel (which is the datacontext of the xaml).

Also the bindings for Message and MessageType appear to work correctly (textbox inside the ContentTemplate which is bound to the Message changes, when Message changes). 

There are no binding errors in the output.

Comment: It's working for me in the same configuration. Maybe try explicitly setting the UpdateSourceTrigger

Comment: I have tried that and it still doesn't work. There must be something different in our projects outside of the code snippets I have provided originally. 
I have updated OP with a simplified project with all the code necessary to run the application, could you check if it still works for you?

Comment: Apparently the storyboard indead won't update the Binding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240596/why-bindings-dont-work-with-animations
You could incorporate this behavior in your Control with a DispatcherTimer instead.